# How to Extract code from annotation @Getter?

Tags: java, restfb, lombok

```
package com.restfb.types;

import static com.restfb.util.StringUtils.isBlank;

import com.restfb.Facebook;
import com.restfb.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * Base class which encapsulates behavior and properties common to most
 * <a href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/">Graph API types</a>.
 * 
 * @author <a href="http://restfb.com">Mark Allen</a>
 * @since 1.5
 */
public class FacebookType implements Serializable {

  /**
   * This object's unique Facebook ID.
   * 
   * @return This object's unique Facebook ID.
   */
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Facebook
  private String id;

}
```

This is a restfb code and I am not able to find how to replace annotation @Getter or @Setter with code inside them.I am using eclipse ide and i already installed lombok in my eclipse.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract code from annotation" or by "replace annotation"? Lombok has a built-in annotation processor that _replaces_ them during compilation. Their web presentation has clear [documentation how to run lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html). If there is anything unclear for you, what exactly?

Comment: I have a source code like above which contain @Getter annotation and i want that this annotation should replace by its source code and I want to see that code, for this i have successfully installed lombok and add lombok.jar in my project and I run this  program and it runs fine but i am not able to see source code. So my question is how to saw source code which after replace that notation.

Comment: It is not the _source code_ that is changed by these annotations. It is the generated _byte code_ that has the changes. The compiler looks for any annotation processors in the class path while compiling. That's the reason, why you have to put the lombok jar file into the class path when compiling.

Comment: By the way: After installing lombok into eclipse, you will have the generated methods (getters, setters, ...) in the outline view - but still not in the source code.

Comment: ya so what should i do to have theses method in my source code?

Comment: I am not aware of any tool that changes the source code, but you could write it yourself. Alternatively, why not simply writing those methods into the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process you are interested in is called "delombok". I am not aware of an Eclipse plugin that does that (There is one for Intellij). But you can still use the command line tool for that from project Lombok. Details are [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html). In summary, you can ran from the command line

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok -p FacebookType.java
```

You need to set the correct path for `lombok.jar` and your file that I assume is named `FacebookType.java`. You can also perform that for all files in your src folder :

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok src -d src-delomboked
```

`src` being the folder with source files that use Lombok annotations and `src-delomboked` the output folder.

There also seems to be a [maven plugin](https://github.com/awhitford/lombok.maven) that you can potentially user for that purpose.

Comment: Ya thanks its work like a charm, it created new folder name src-delomboked at same place and folder contains all java files with the source that i want to see, now suppose i changes some source of a code and then how can i able to lomboked that and merge it with my actual src folder?Let me know if my question is not clear

Comment: I don't think it's possible to re-lombok a file with annotations after you manually modify the auto-generated code. You can simply overwrite this particular file with the delomboked version and keep using Lombok annotations in the other files.

Comment: Ok Sir Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: It even makes no sense. The `@Getter` annotation is used to reduce boilerplate code. As soon as you need a smarter getter, you have to implement that method and remove the annotation. BTW I answered this in the restfb issue tracker already...